# List of conditions Plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I made a table of conditions, namely conditions that define spheres. But I can't plot those in "RegionPlot3D", I would really like to know what I can do to surpass this problem.

When I get the condition, the "squares" appear in mathematical notation $(x-1)^2$ like this instead of $(x-1) \wedge$ 2, I don't know if it generates some kind of problem

Here is the code:

`Equacoes[2]`, gives the table of conditions based on the argument 2.

It returns

```
{(5 + x)^2 + (-10 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2 <= 10000,
 (-21 + x)^2 + (-4 + y)^2 + (-9 + z)^2 <= 10000}
```

When I try plotting it

```
RegionPlot3D[Equacoes[2],{x,-100,100},{y,-100,100},{z,-100,100}]
```

It gives the following warning:

`Equacoes[2]` must be a boolean function

Comment: Please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/245301/edit) your question, and add the code you've tried. Posting the code makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @creidhne just did it, thanks for the advice

Comment: Try `RegionPlot3D[Evaluate[Equacoes[2]],{x,-100,100},{y,-100,100},{z,-100,100}]`. What happens then?

Comment: @thorimur It worked :). Thanks so much

Comment: You made several basic syntactic errors. The correct code is as follows: `RegionPlot3D[(5 + x)^2 + (\[Minus]10 + y)^2 + (\[Minus]3 + z)^2 <= 
   10000 && (\[Minus]21 + x)^2 + (\[Minus]4 + y)^2 + (\[Minus]9 + 
      z)^2 <= 10000, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -110, 110}]`. Try it.

Comment: In general, I vote to close this question as off-topic, since it is based on elementary syntactic errors. The answer to such a question is easily found in Help.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I don't think the problem was syntactic errors per se; it was the (admittedly still elementary) fact that plotting functions sort of don't evaluate their first argument, so you need an `Evaluate`. I think this was obscured by the use of LaTeX formatting instead of code fences.

Comment: @ thorimur Please look at the code I gave in my previous comment. There I only used the code elements given in the question of OP, but supplied them with the correct syntax, nothing else. The use of Latex in Mma is the incorrect syntax by itself. However, the OP gave some code in Mma notation, but with slightly incorrect syntax. From my point of view, this is not bad, and I gave OP the suitable code. However, I believe that the question represents no interest for other users. This is my reason to vote to close it.